# Monitoring disk I/O on hadoop cluster with ganglia

Tags: performance, hadoop, metrics, ganglia

I deployed hadoop 2 (HDP2), and would like to get the disk i/o metrics of my slave nodes in ganglia. I didn't find any relevant metric so far.

What metric do you suggest to use or to add to ganglia ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Ganglia Python Module Disk-stat provided [here](https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/diskstat)

Comment: Can you explain how to use Ganglia Python Module Disk-stat? Thank you very much . github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/diskstat.

Answer (score 1):

[cloudera-manager](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-manager.html) can help monitor the cluster status including Disk I/O

Answer (score 1):

As stated by @vishnu: Ganglia Python Module Disk-stat provided [here](https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/diskstat)

You can also use gmetric scripts that you would run from cron from [here](https://github.com/ganglia/gmetric/tree/master/disk)

Finally, you can use collectl and export disk metrics to ganglia, see [here](http://collectl.sourceforge.net/Export.html)

Comment: Can you explain how to use Ganglia Python Module Disk-stat? Thank you very much . https://github.com/ganglia/gmond_python_modules/tree/master/diskstat.